# boolean to string in TableView JavaFx

Tags: string, javafx, boolean, tableview

im trying to display a boolean value as a string in a tableview so instead of true i want to display male.

i'm a bit lost with it to be honest. i cant find anything on the internet to help.

the error ecilpse is giving me is The method " setCellValueFactory(Callback,ObservableValue>) in the type TableColumn is not applicable for the arguments (( cellData) -> {})"

heres my code. its probably wrong

```
TableColumn<Animal, String > genColumn = new TableColumn<>("Male");
        genColumn.setMinWidth(50);
        genColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            boolean gender = cellData.getValue().getGender();
            String genderAsString;
            if(gender == true)
            {
                genderAsString = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                genderAsString = "Female";
            }

            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(genderAsString);
        });
```

i would be grateful for any help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i managed to get it working i was just missing the return statement.

heres the code

```
TableColumn<Animal, String > genColumn = new TableColumn<>("Gender");
        genColumn.setMinWidth(50);
        genColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            boolean gender = cellData.getValue().getGender();
            String genderAsString;
            if(gender == true)
            {
                genderAsString = "Male";
            }
            else
            {
                genderAsString = "Female";
            }

         return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(genderAsString);
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

Keep the type as boolean and use a cell factory to change the way you display it:

```
TableColumn<Animal, Boolean> genColumn = new TableColumn<>("Gender");
genColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().genderProperty());
// or cellData -> new SimpleBooleanProperty(cellData.getValue().getGender())
// if your model class doesn't use JavaFX properties

genColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Animal, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        setText(empty ? null : item ? "Male" : "Female" );
    }
});
```